# Проблема с init?()

Tags: swift

Есть вот такой код (// после написана сама ошибка )

```
    struct CurrentData {
    let sliksLable: String
    let numbeLable: String
    let nameLable: String
    
    
    init?(currentDataData: CurrentDataData){
        nameLable = currentDataData.company.employees.first?.name ?? ""
        numbeLable = currentDataData.company.employees.first?.phoneNumber ?? ""
        sliksLable = currentDataData.company.employees.first?.skills //Cannot assign value of type '[String]?' to type 'String'
    }
}
```

создал приложения с лабле в которое надо передать данные с сервера, данные выглядят так:

```
    {
      company: {
          name: "Avito",
          employees: [
        {
             name: "John",
             phone_number: "769453",
             skills: [
                 "Swift",
                 "iOS"
                  ]
         },
         {
             name: "Diego",
             phone_number: "987924",
             skills: [
                  "Kotlin",
                  "Android"
                 ]
         },
         {
             name: "Alfred",
             phone_number: "452533",
             skills: [
                 "Objective-C",
                 "Android",
                 "Photoshop"
                 ]
         },
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Я этот язык не знаю, но, видимо, переменная должна быть `nullable`, не знаю как тут это пишется, может так: `let sliksLable: String?` Ну либо вместо этого само присваивание закончить как и предыдущие: `... .first?.skills ?? ""`

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, все оказалось проще ем я думал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть была простая неправильный тип у переменной let sliksLable: String, он должен быть let sliksLable: [String]